# Why is Tradozone prescribed to aid with insomnia?

Tags: medications, insomnia, antidepressants

Per [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trazodone#Insomnia):

> Many clinicians use low-dose trazodone as an alternative to benzodiazepines for the treatment of insomnia. Two recent reviews found that trazodone is the second most prescribed agent for insomnia [...]

Is there any scientific explanation of the mechanism in action?

Comment: "This medication is used to treat depression. It may help to improve your mood, appetite, and energy level as well as decrease anxiety and insomnia related to depression." ([WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-11188-89/trazodone-oral/trazodone-oral/details))

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yeah, I already know that, the question is why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pharmacology:** Inhibits reuptake of serotonin, causes adrenoreceptor subsensitivity, acts as a 5HT2a receptor antagonist and induces significant changes in 5-HT presynaptic receptor adrenoreceptors. **Trazodone also significantly blocks histamine (H1) and alpha1-adrenergic receptors.**

**Insomnia (off-label use):** **Oral: Immediate release: Usual dose: 50 mg to 100 mg at bedtime (Kaynak 2004; Roth 2011; Walsh 1998).** Doses up to 600 mg have been evaluated in patients with insomnia associated with depression (typical ranges of 50 to 300 mg); however, the quality of the evidence precludes definitive conclusions of efficacy (Mendelson 2005; Sateia 2017). Additional data may be necessary to further define the role of trazodone in this condition.

**Simple Summary: Mechanism of Action--> Trazodone blocks H1 receptors. By blocking those receptors the effect is (usually) drowsiness.**

**References**

Kaynak H, Kaynak D, Gözükirmizi E, Guilleminault C. The effects of trazodone on sleep in patients treated with stimulant antidepressants. Sleep Med. 2004;5(1):15-20.[PubMed 14725822]

Roth AJ, Mc Call WV, Liguori A. Cognitive, psychomotor and polysomnographic effects of trazodone in primary insomniacs. J Sleep Res. 2011;20(4):552-558.[PubMed 21623982]

Walsh JK, Erman M, Erwin CW, et al. Subjective hypnotic efficacy of trazodone and zolpidem in DSMIII-R primary insomnia. Human Psychopharmacology. 1998:13;191-198.

Mendelson WH. A review of the evidence for the efficacy and safety of trazodone in insomnia. J Clin Psych. 2005;66(4):469-476.[PubMed 15816789]